# Rearrangement Inequality Theorem - Proof

Tags: inequality, permutations, proof-explanation, rearrangement-inequality

The theorem states that the sum $S=a_1b_1 + . . . + a_nb_n$ is a maximum if  two strings $a_1,...,a_n$ and $b_1,...,b_n$ have the same order. Let's assume $a_1<a_2<...<a_n$ and $b_1<b_2<...<b_n$.
The proof from my book is this one ( the same I sensed at the first glance):

> Let $a_r>a_s  (b_r>b_s)$. Consider the sums:
>
> $S_1=a_1b_1+...+a_rb_r+...+a_sb_s+...+a_nb_n,$
>
> $S_2=a_1b_1+...+a_rb_s+...+a_sb_r+...+a_nb_n.$
>
> We obtain $S_2$ from $S_1$ by replacing $b_s$ with $b_r$. Hence
>
> $S_2-S_1=a_rb_s+a_sb_r-a_rb_r-a_sb_s=(a_r-a_s)(b_s-b_r)<0$
>
> We deduce that $S_1>S_2$.

This is their proof. But it's not enough for me because of this:
Let's assume the strings are big enough and have at least one element between the positions $r$ and $s$ in the strings ( denoted by $i$, $r<i<s$ ), where $a_1<...<a_i<...<a_n$ and $b_1<...<b_i<...<b_n$. The only way through which we can obtain from $S_2$ a bigger sum than $S_2$ using rearrangements is to interchange $b_r$ with the "$b$ factor" of one of the terms between $a_rb_s$ and $a_sb_r$ in $S_2$, i.e. $b_i$. By doing this we obtain the following sum from $S_2$:

> $S_3=a_1b_1+...+a_rb_s+...+a_ib_r+...+a_sb_i+...+a_nb_n.$

This sum is bigger than $S_2$ if you try to prove it.
Even though I could prove that $S_3>S_1$, it is pointless as my aim is to find the generalization in their proof or at least another general one, but I just can't seem to succeed. I hope you could help me with a proof for this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: here you can find a proof http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Rearrangement_Inequality

Comment: There are only finitely many permutations, hence a maximum exists. If an arrangement does not have parallel order, then you can find a larger value. What more do you think is needed?

Comment: We don't need to find a sum bigger than $S_2.$  We just need to show that every other  sum $S_2$ is greater or equal to   $S_1$.... Also we do not need to assume  strict inequality anywhere. Replace every "$<$" with "$\leq$".... And (although this may be  a typo) it should say  "$a_r\geq a_s\land b_s\geq b_r$ when $r>s$."

Answer (score 6):

We can prove it by induction.

For $n=2$ we need to prove that
$$a_1b_2+a_2b_1\leq a_1b_1+a_2b_2$$ or
$$(a_1-a_2)(b_1-b_2)\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Let $\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_ib_{\sigma(i)}\leq\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_ib_i$ for all $a_1\leq a_2\leq...\leq a_n$, $b_1\leq b_2\leq...\leq b_n$ for all $n\geq2$ and  $\sigma\in S_n$.

Now, let $a_1\leq a_2\leq...\leq a_n\leq a_{n+1}$, $b_1\leq b_2\leq...\leq b_n\leq b_{n+1}$ and $\sigma\in S_{n+1}$.

We'll prove that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}a_ib_{\sigma(i)}\leq\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}a_ib_i.$$
If $\sigma(n+1)=n+1$ then by the induction assumption we are done.

Let $\sigma(n+1)=j$ and $\sigma^{-1}(n+1)=k$, where $j\neq n+1$.

Thus, 
$$a_1b_{\sigma(1)}+...+a_kb_{n+1}+...+a_{n+1}b_j\leq a_1b_{\sigma(i)}+...+a_kb_j+...+a_{n+1}b_{n+1}\leq\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}a_ib_{\sigma(i)}$$
and we are done!